How to implement multiple insertion operators (<<) for a C++ class?
I output my class objects using cout or ofstream. I understood that the insertion operator << is the standard way to convert an object to a string or print it. I would like to use different formats in different parts of the project.
I would like to have many different string formats for the class. However, there could be only one insertion operator for the class.
What are the common ways to solve this in C++?
One solution I have used is to have multiple functions returning strings. My understanding is that overloading the insertion operator is the most common way to output objects and I would like to have that kind of solution.
Using different formats sounds like the strategy pattern. I guess a template is also a powerful tool for a lot of problems. I am not familiar with either kind of solution.
Here is a code example to demonstrate the problem:
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class Point {
  public:
    Point(int x, int y): x(x), y(y) {}

    std::string to_string() {
      std::ostringstream stream;
      stream << "(" << x << ", " << y << ")";
      return stream.str();
    }   

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Point& p) {
      return out << p.x << " " << p.y;
    }   

  private:
    int x, y;
};

int main() {
  Point p { 4, 2 };
  std::cout << p << std::endl;
  std::cout << p.to_string() << std::endl;
}

I would like to get rid of the to_string function and use insertion operators to get all formats. What is an easy way to define which format insertion operator is using. It should be possible to change the format of the object.
There could be more than two different formats for the class.

your solution is ok. Of course there are different ways, but if you do not want a to_string what else do you want? std::cout << p; for one format and what for the other?

If you can use c++20 there is std::format that allows you to have printf like output strings but type safety.  std::formatter can be specialized for your type to get it to work with std::format

This will let you have a default and then you can manually specify any special formatting you want at the call site.

You could make your own I/O stream manipulator, and have your own classes's stream operators behavior depending on your customer manipulator state you've injected into the stream.  q.v. custom C++ stream manipulators.  I went that route once, and have concluded it was not the solution for my problem (I/O in one of four ways: binary-for-file, text-for-file, text-for-user-facing, text-for-debugging).  But maybe it is a solution appropriate for your problem.

You can define your own I/O stream manipulators for this task. You can either:

wrap the Point object with another struct/class type that you overload operator<< for, eg:

#include <iostream>

class Point {
  public:
    Point(int x, int y): x(x), y(y) {}
  private:
    int x, y;
    friend struct s_Point_printer;
};

struct s_Point_printer {
    const Point &m_pt;
    const bool m_parenthesis;

    s_Point_printer(const Point &pt, bool parenthesis) : m_pt(pt), m_parenthesis(parenthesis) {}

    void printTo(std::ostream &out) const {
        if (m_parenthesis)
            out << "(" << m_pt.x << ", " << m_pt.y << ")";
        else
            out << m_pt.x << " " << m_pt.y;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const s_Point_printer &printer) {
        printer.printTo(out);
        return out;
    }
};

s_Point_printer with_parens( const Point& pt ) {
    return s_Point_printer{pt, true};
}

s_Point_printer without_parens( const Point& pt ) {
    return s_Point_printer{pt, false};
}

int main() {
  Point p { 4, 2 };
  std::cout << without_parens(p) << std::endl; // prints "4 2"
  std::cout << with_parens(p) << std::endl;    // prints "(4, 2)"
}

Online Demo

Alternatively, you can store your desired formatting option directly inside the std::ostream itself, and then have your overloaded operator<< for Point check that option, eg:

class Point {
  public:
    static int point_xalloc;

    Point(int x, int y): x(x), y(y) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& pt) {
        if (os.iword(Point::point_xalloc) == 1)
            return os << "(" << pt.x << ", " << pt.y << ")";
        else
            return os << pt.x << " " << pt.y;
    }

  private:
    int x, y;
};
 
int Point::point_xalloc = std::ios_base::xalloc();

std::ios_base& with_parens(std::ios_base& os) {
    os.iword(Point::point_xalloc) = 1;
    return os;
}
 
std::ios_base& without_parens(std::ios_base& os) {
    os.iword(Point::point_xalloc) = 0;
    return os;
}

int main() {
  Point p { 4, 2 };
  std::cout << without_parens << p << std::endl; // prints "4 2"
  std::cout << with_parens << p << std::endl;    // prints "(4, 2)"
}

Online Demo
